# Android studio text editor erases text instead of allowing normal edit

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have worked with several IDE and code editors but this android studio am using is a real mess, when I place a cursor in the code i want to edit or add code to it, instead of allowing normal edit it just deletes what ever code is there and replaces it with what I type.

For example if i the space key between the public and void it will erase the void instead of creating the space am requesting it to provide.

Comment: Sounds like the insert-mode is off, try pressing the 'Insert' or 'Ins' button on your keyboard to turn on 'Insert' mode (this functionality is not specific to Android Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have the 'ins' pressed on your keypad.

Press numlock, and then 0 to turn off the insert function. If it doesnt work, try pressing the numlock again and then press 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly caused by pressing Insert key in your keyboard.
To solve this just press Insert key once.

OR

make sure that NumLock is Off (light indicating num lock is off) then press 0 in numberpad.

NOTE (0 key  has Insert function as secondary function - i.e NumLock key function as FN key works ===> Or less realistically as Shift key).